# Can I come to the US 60 days after school has resumed?

Tags: usa

So i wanted to know something, Suppose I am supposed to start in say January (Spring) in the US, Can i come into the US say after 30 - 60 days after school has resumed? Please I want to understand this very clearly for the sake of clarity.

Comment: What will you have been doing in the 30-60 days between school starting and you arriving? Does your school know you won't be there? Have they given you permission not to be there? Is your US visa a student visa?

Comment: @DJClayworth i would have to seek their permission, but i wanted to know of the possibility after taking permission and yes, its a study permit.

Comment: Will you be enrolled at the school that semester? How will you keep up with classes?

Comment: @JonCuster, yes i would. Just trying to understand and close out with some deliverables in my home country in order to embark on a fulltime course in the US, thats what i needed to know.

Comment: It is certainly conceivable that you risk additional scrutiny at the border, given the late arrival for the semester. I would check and double-check with the school's international office for any guidance and assistance they might have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need a very good reason for your late arrival, and will need permission from your school. The school may insist that you defer your start until the next term, or even the next year, if they believe that you will have missed too much of the course to be able to catch up.

In visa terms if the school agrees to your late start you will need [a "late arrival permission letter" from your school](https://ois.usc.edu/new-students/arrivingintheus/#:%7E:text=Late%20Entry&text=In%20general%2C%20a%20student%20cannot,a%20late%20arrival%20permission%20letter.)  which you should be prepared to present to immigration.

> In general, a student cannot arrive more than one week after classes start and must be enrolled full time for that semester. Students who are not able to enter the U.S. by the program start date on the I-20/DS-2019 must contact their academic department to request a late arrival permission letter.

Starting 30-60 days late is going to involve a huge amount of work, and it may be in your own interests to defer your start until the course takes in new students again, usually a term or a year later.

Comment: OK. I understand now.

Comment: If this answer is what you were looking for, please vote it up and accept it by clicking the tick mark on the left.